# installr does not copy over packages to new version of R

Tags: r, package, installr

I recently used the [installr](/questions/tagged/installr) package to update my version of R (from 3.6.2 to 4.0.0). The update was successful, and I have confirmed using `print(R.version)`. However, my packages from the old version of R have not copied over to the new version, despite me following [these](https://www.r-statistics.com/2015/06/a-step-by-step-screenshots-tutorial-for-upgrading-r-on-windows/) steps to the letter. I have also tried to run `copy.packages.between.libraries(ask = T)` to copy the packages over. Both times returned `No packages to copy.  Goodbye :)`, despite me being unable to load any of the packages previously installed on the old version.

Comment: I just had the same problem.

Comment: You could try a [manual migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353392/how-to-update-r-from-3-x-to-4-x-and-should-i/62353652#62353652)

Comment: @Waldi Thank you! Though I'm more interested in the cause of the bug.

Answer (score 9):

This is because updating from R 3.6.x to 4.x requires that you reinstall all packages (see the [news](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html)).

The best way I found of doing this is:

1. get your old packages

   ```
   old_packages <- installed.packages(lib.loc = "/home/johannes/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/")
   ```

Of course, you have to change the path to the one where your packages live. Simply use `.libPaths()` and if you've already installed the new R version, replace the `4.0` with `3.6`.

2. check the old against the already installed packages:

   ```
   new_packages <- installed.packages()
   missing_df <- as.data.frame(old_packages[
     !old_packages[, "Package"] %in% new_packages[, "Package"], 
     ])
   ```
3. install missing packages (use multiple cores for extra speed)

   `install.packages(missing_df$Package, Ncpus = 3)`

I wrote this up on my blog some time ago [here](https://www.johannesbgruber.eu/post/get-all-your-packages-back-on-r-4-0-0/), but these are the essential steps and you should be good to go.

Comment: "This is because updating from R 3.6.x to 4.x requires that you reinstall all packages" Ah I see! Is it known why is that?

Comment: Not really. I just noticed it when looking at the [official change log](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) "Packages need to be (re-)installed under this version (4.0.0) of R."

Comment: i had the same problem when updating version 4.0.2 to 4.1.0. I said yes to move packages from old to new version and yes to update packages. Any user package was moved from folder 4.0 to 4.1. i had to use this answer to reinstall all packages.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a look at the source code of `copy.packages.between.libraries` (just type `F2` when your mouse pointer is on the function name), you find the following commands :

```r
library(installr)

(installed_R_folders <- get.installed.R.folders())
#>                   4.0.3                   4.0.2 
#> "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.3" "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2"
(installed_R_folders_TABLE <- data.frame(R_version = names(installed_R_folders), 
                                        Folder = installed_R_folders))
#>       R_version                Folder
#> 4.0.3     4.0.3 C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.3
#> 4.0.2     4.0.2 C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2
(from <- installed_R_folders[2])
#>                   4.0.2 
#> "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2"
(to <- installed_R_folders[1])
#>                   4.0.3 
#> "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.3"
(from_library <- file.path(from, "library"))
#> [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.2/library"
(to_library <- file.path(to, "library"))
#> [1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.0.3/library"
(packages_in_the_from_library <- list.files(from_library))
#>  [1] "base"         "boot"         "class"        "cluster"      "codetools"   
#>  [6] "compiler"     "datasets"     "foreign"      "graphics"     "grDevices"   
#> [11] "grid"         "KernSmooth"   "lattice"      "MASS"         "Matrix"      
#> [16] "methods"      "mgcv"         "nlme"         "nnet"         "parallel"    
#> [21] "rpart"        "spatial"      "splines"      "stats"        "stats4"      
#> [26] "survival"     "tcltk"        "tools"        "translations" "utils"
(packages_in_the_to_library <- list.files(to_library))
#>  [1] "base"         "boot"         "class"        "cluster"      "codetools"   
#>  [6] "compiler"     "datasets"     "foreign"      "graphics"     "grDevices"   
#> [11] "grid"         "KernSmooth"   "lattice"      "MASS"         "Matrix"      
#> [16] "methods"      "mgcv"         "nlme"         "nnet"         "parallel"    
#> [21] "rpart"        "spatial"      "splines"      "stats"        "stats4"      
#> [26] "survival"     "tcltk"        "tools"        "translations" "utils"
(packages_to_NOT_move <- unname(installed.packages(priority = "high")[,"Package"]))
#>  [1] "codetools"  "base"       "boot"       "class"      "cluster"   
#>  [6] "codetools"  "compiler"   "datasets"   "foreign"    "graphics"  
#> [11] "grDevices"  "grid"       "KernSmooth" "lattice"    "MASS"      
#> [16] "Matrix"     "methods"    "mgcv"       "nlme"       "nnet"      
#> [21] "parallel"   "rpart"      "spatial"    "splines"    "stats"     
#> [26] "stats4"     "survival"   "tcltk"      "tools"      "utils"
(packages_to_NOT_move <- c(packages_to_NOT_move, packages_in_the_to_library))
#>  [1] "codetools"    "base"         "boot"         "class"        "cluster"     
#>  [6] "codetools"    "compiler"     "datasets"     "foreign"      "graphics"    
#> [11] "grDevices"    "grid"         "KernSmooth"   "lattice"      "MASS"        
#> [16] "Matrix"       "methods"      "mgcv"         "nlme"         "nnet"        
#> [21] "parallel"     "rpart"        "spatial"      "splines"      "stats"       
#> [26] "stats4"       "survival"     "tcltk"        "tools"        "utils"       
#> [31] "base"         "boot"         "class"        "cluster"      "codetools"   
#> [36] "compiler"     "datasets"     "foreign"      "graphics"     "grDevices"   
#> [41] "grid"         "KernSmooth"   "lattice"      "MASS"         "Matrix"      
#> [46] "methods"      "mgcv"         "nlme"         "nnet"         "parallel"    
#> [51] "rpart"        "spatial"      "splines"      "stats"        "stats4"      
#> [56] "survival"     "tcltk"        "tools"        "translations" "utils"
(ss_packages_to_NOT_move_from <- packages_in_the_from_library %in% 
  packages_to_NOT_move)
#>  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
#> [16] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
(ss_packages_to_YES_move_from <- !ss_packages_to_NOT_move_from)
#>  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
(packages_to_YES_move_from <- packages_in_the_from_library[ss_packages_to_YES_move_from])
#> character(0)
```

Which comes to the conclusion there's no difference between the packages of the different R installations and leads to:

> No packages to copy.  Goodbye :)

However, if you look at `.libPaths()`, you see that `get.installed.R.folders` is missing the packages you installed on your own user's library:

```
.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library"
```

So default behaviour of `installr` is missing all the packages you installed after R installation :

```
packages <- as.data.frame(utils::installed.packages())
head(packages[is.na(packages$Priority),c("Package","LibPath")])

arrow                               arrow C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
arules                             arules C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
arulesViz                       arulesViz C:/User/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
ash                                   ash C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
askpass                           askpass C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
assertive                       assertive C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
...
```

Comment: Nice analysis of the problem. The solution will not work though, I think. The command `copy.packages.between.libraries` will use `file.copy` eventually. And as far as I read the [change log](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) (look for "CHANGES IN R 4.0.0"), the copied files will be broken/useless due to changes in `R` 4.0.0. .

Comment: @JBGruber, in comments to the post OP is actually interested in the cause of the bug. If `copy.packages.beween.libraries`doesn't work `install.packages` will do.

Comment: @JBGruber, thanks for you comment on `file.copy` in `copy.between.packegs` : I remove the last workaround, you're right it won't work.