# How to update R from 3.x to 4.x and should I?

Tags: r

With R 4.0.0 and recently R 4.0.1 being released recently, I would like to know how to upgrade?

Previously I used `UpdateR()` from the `installR` package.

Will it work just as well upgrading to 4.x?

The documentation for 4.0.0 states that:

**Packages need to be (re-)installed under this version (4.0.0) of R**

Will updateR re-install everything and if not, how can I get list of packages to install in a reasonable amount of time.

I cannot believe I can't find any 4.x install or update details elsewhere, most importantly are there any specific issues or limitation or code changes required in 4.x from 3.x.

**Also** I use Rbuild Tools for Rcpp. Do I need to update those tools to 4.0 as well and is there a special way to do so?

Comment: You can have multiple version of R installed at the same time. Installing 4 doesn't replace 3. Just try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this a few weeks ago.
UpdateR didn't migrate the packages as expected, so that I had to do it manually :

- Install [R 4.0.x](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)
- Install [RTools 4.0](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/), take care to [set $Path correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241983/i-dont-know-what-rtools-path-should-be/62242456#62242456) as instructed. This new version is necessary for R 4.0 to compile from source some packages still in 3.x
- Migrate the packages from R 3.x to R 4.x :

```
# locate packages
.libPaths()
[1] "/Documents/R/win-library/4.0" 
# Migration list : replace previous 4.0 by 3.x in old_lib_loc
old_lib_loc <- "/Documents/R/win-library/3.x"
to_install <- unname(installed.packages(lib.loc = old_lib_loc)[, "Package"])
# Check if list is OK or if you want to clean up
to_install
[1] "abind"                "acepack"              "ada"                  "alphavantager"                   
[6] "ash"                  "askpass"              "assertive"            "assertive.base"       "assertive.code"  
# Migrate
install.packages(pkgs = to_install,Ncpus = 4)
```

Packages still in 3.x are automatically recompiled from source.
That's it, no problems encountered since then.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I always have issues with just 3.x updates. I have hours of work ahead of me. I will update on how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked, and honestly even better than a typical upgrade with UpdateR some packages where not on Cran for 4.x yet, so I used somthing like **devtools::install_github("r-lib/vctrs")**. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Waldi. Some tips for others. 1) I had an empty `to_install` list so I was more explicit in my `old_lib_loc` path using old_lib_loc <- "C:/users/USERNAME/Documents/R/...etc". 2) Look out for CRAN mirror list popup which might not be on same screen as your R window.

Answer (score -2):

First, you should run:
this will remove R

```
    $ sudo apt remove r-base
```

then type this, so you can add the GPG Key

```
    $ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Now add this repo

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
```

then update your packages list

```
    $ sudo apt update
```

now install R

```
    $ sudo apt install r-base
```

Comment: This a terrible idea , do NOT do that please. It will break all your install.