# I updated my R version and need to move my packages from the old version to the new version

Tags: r, package, r-package

My current R version is `R 4.1.0` and my `.libPaths()` are

```
[1] “C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1”
[2] “C:/R/R-4.1.0/library”
```

I don't know why most of my packages are stored in `“C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1”` rather than `“C:/R/R-4.1.0/library”`

I updated to R version `R 4.3.2` using `installr` package and `updateR` function and my `.libPaths()` are

```
[1] “C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3”
[2] “C:/R/R-4.3.2/library”
```

I need to transfer/copy my packages from `“C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1”` which is the old version

to

`“C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3”` which is one of the `.libPaths()` of my new R version.

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Next time, you may wanna use `installr::updater()` which does an entire update on your R-version and also the packages to their newer version all to their default directories

Comment: I literally used `installr` package and `updateR` function to update the R version.

Comment: perhaps have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62353652/13513328

Comment: @Rothschild Ah so the migrate option pop-up did not work as intended?

Comment: This is something I haven't done in a while, but what worked for me was just installing new packages as I needed them. This was a one time task and didn't take much of my time. Since I've been using `renv`, I install dependencies project-wide from a `renv.lock` file and I don't care about my "global" packages anymore.

Comment: @Derf I think it only migrated the packages in `C:/R/R-4.1.0/library` which are very few. It didn't migrate the packages in `C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1`

Comment: @Waldi, thanks for the link. I'll act accordingly